# Not able to pull from nested array and query return sub-document using MongoTemplate

Tags: mongodb, spring-data, mongotemplate

I am using mongodb in springboot. And here is a part of my data:

```
{
  "topic": [
    {
      "_topicId": "5e5e4d4bb431502946c15342",
      "name": "testName0",
      "username": "test0",
      "date": 1583238474961,
      "reply": [
        {
          "_replyId": "38d29dcb-1a79-4788-b721-5fbe700cc99d",
          "username": "test0",
          "content": "reply0",
          "date": 1583240780072
        },
        {
          "_replyId": "07a0293a-22a1-45fb-9aa2-775fa24e9915",
          "username": "test1",
          "content": "reply1",
          "date": 1583240955561
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "_topicId": "5e5e4d4bb431502946c15343",
      "name": "testName1",
      "username": "test1",
      "date": 1583238475241,
      "reply": []
    }
  ]
}
```

I have two problems:

**(1)** I try to pull a `reply`(a object of in java) from a `topic`, I try these queries:

```java
Query query = Query.query(Criteria.where("_topicId").is(topicId));
Update update = new Update().pull("reply.$._replyId", topicReplyId);
mongoTemplate.updateFirst(query, update, "colletionName");
```

And I got a error **The positional operator did not find the match needed from the query**

```java
Query query = Query.query(Criteria.where("_topicId").is(topicId));
Update update = new Update().pull("reply._replyId", topicReplyId);
mongoTemplate.updateFirst(query, update, "colletionName");
```

And I got a error **Cannot use the part (_replyId) of (reply._replyId) to traverse the element**

Then I decide to use the third way:

```java
Query query = Query.query(Criteria.where("_topicId").is(topicId));
Update update = new Update().pull("reply", replyEntity);
mongoTemplate.updateFirst(query, update, "colletionName");
```

I try to new a `ReplyEntity` replyEntity, and I got my ***second problem***:

**(2)** How can I get the subdocument from a document?

```java
Query query = Query.query(Criteria.where("_topicId").is(topicId).and("reply._replyId").is(replyId));
TopicEntity t = mongoTemplate.findOne(query, TopicEntity.class, "colletionName");
```

I used the query but I get the outer-document(`topic`), include two `reply` on the example above of topic1.
I just want the `reply`,how can make it? Thanks a lot.

Comment: The [$pull](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/pull/index.html) update operator removes (or pulls from an array) the specified element. For example, you can _pull_ the `reply` with the `replyId = "07a0293a-22a1-45fb-9aa2-775fa24e9915"`. The resulting document will _not_ have that particular sub-document element in the `reply` array.  Is that what you want to achieve?

Comment: @prasad_ Thanks for you comment. Your comment is one part of what I want to achieve. I understand the `pull` operation ,but I can't use it correctly, which means I can't `pull` the reply with the replyId = "07a0293a-22a1-45fb-9aa2-775fa24e9915",my `query` and `update` are always wrong.

Comment: Okay, I will post some code, based on my comment.

Comment: For the question _(2)_, on querying the specific element from a nested array (array within array) you have to use Aggregation query. The `find` method's positional projection operator `$` doesn't work with more than one-level nesting. The aggregation `$project` (or `addFields`) stage and [$filter](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/filter/) operator can be used for the query.

Comment: I added the aggregation query for the question (2). Note that I didn't use the `$filter` approach, as the output needed to be just the `reply` sub-document. The query uses the `$unwind` and `$match` stages to get the specific sub-document in the nested array.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**(1) Update (pull) `reply` array element:**

This code will update the document; that is removes the specific element (sub-document) from the `reply` array:

```
// Query criteria for topic and reply
String topicId = "5e5e4d4bb431502946c15342";
String topicReplyId = "07a0293a-22a1-45fb-9aa2-775fa24e9915";

MongoOperations mongoTemplate = new MongoTemplate(MongoClients.create(), "test");
Query query = Query.query(Criteria
                               .where("topic._topicId").is(topicId)
                               .and("topic.reply._replyId").is(topicReplyId));
Update update = new Update().pull("topic.$.reply", new Document("_replyId", topicReplyId));
mongoTemplate.updateFirst(query, update, "topics"); // "topics" is the collection name
```

---

*[ EDIT ADD ]*

**(2) Aggregation query to get the `reply` document:**

```
db.topics.aggregate( [
  { $unwind: "$topic" },
  { $match: { "topic._topicId": topicId } },
  { $unwind: "$topic.reply" },
  { $match: { "topic.reply._replyId": topicReplyId } },
  { $project: { _id: 0, reply: "$topic.reply" } }
] ).pretty()
```

This returns:

```
{
        "reply" : {
                "_replyId" : "07a0293a-22a1-45fb-9aa2-775fa24e9915",
                "username" : "test1",
                "content" : "reply1",
                "date" : 1583240955561
        }
}
```