# spring mongo query update the array elements based on matched condition

Tags: mongodb, spring-data-mongodb, spring-mongodb

How to use spring mongo query criteria based only for below thing.

I don't want to use spring mongo save method even though its doing upsert because of application is running in multi threaded environment so only specified values should updated and remaining values will not change.

Suppose the document looks like:

```
{
        "dept": "FY",
        "companyName": "TIS",
        "id":"112234",
            "contacts": [{
                    "name": "Jeff",
                    "phone": "222 - 572 - 8754"
                },
                {
                    "name": "Joe",
                    "phone": "456 - 875 - 4521"
                },
                
                {
                    "name": "Alex",
                    "phone": "789 - 875 - 4521"
                }
            ]
       
    }
```

based on id  and the array list  passing  to update method the contacts list should update.

Lets take based on id=112234 and passing  contacts list  to update method, based on contact name it should update.

```
"contacts": [{
            "name": "Jeff",
            "phone": "111 - 000 - 123"
        },
        {
            "name": "Joe",
            "phone": "980 - 546 - 0000"
        }
        ]
```

the final  mongo json document should updated as below:

```
{
        "dept": "FY",
        "companyName": "TIS",
        "id":"112234",
            "contacts": [{
                    "name": "Jeff",
                    "phone": "111 - 000 - 123"
                },
                {
                    "name": "Joe",
                    "phone": "980 - 546 - 0000"
                },
                
                {
                    "name": "Alex",
                    "phone": "789 - 875 - 4521"
                }
            ]
       
    }
```

Comment: This post updates with a condition: [Not able to pull from nested array and query return sub-document using MongoTemplate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60510065/not-able-to-pull-from-nested-array-and-query-return-sub-document-using-mongotemp/60520266#60520266)

Comment: @prasad_,provided link is updating only single element in array , but i have multiple matched elements need to be update in a single query. Is it possible to do ?

Comment: Then, use the [filtered positional operator](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/positional-filtered/index.html) with the update.

Comment: even though filtered positional operator setting only single value for example db.getCollection('ss').update(
   { },
   { $set: { "contacts.$[element].phone" : '111 - 000 - 123' } },
   
   {  multi: true,
     arrayFilters: [ { "element.name":   "Jeff"   }  ]
   }
)
 but i need like this  way db.getCollection('ss').update(
   { },
   { $set: { "contacts.$[element].phone" : '111 - 000 - 123' } },
    { $set: { "contacts.$[element].phone" : '980 - 546 - 0000' } },  
   {  multi: true,
     arrayFilters: [ { "element.name":   "Jeff"   } ,{ "element.name":   "Joe"   } ]
   }
)

Comment: Is there any way to do like in a single short?

Comment: See this post which uses the _filtered positional operator_: [How to add a json in a nested array of a mongodb document using Spring?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60701824/how-to-add-a-json-in-a-nested-array-of-a-mongodb-document-using-spring/60962573#60962573)