# How to Delete nested objects in array in Spring MongoDB

Tags: java, spring, mongodb, mongotemplate

I have a Spring project with MongoDB. I don't have a domain class because my project treats data in a generic way.
I'm trying to delete some objects that I have inside an array but I can't. I've already searched StackOverflow but the information found didn't help me fix this. Here is a summarized example of a Document in my Collection:

```
{ _id
  dispositivos:[
            { uid },
            { uid }
}
```

I try to delete only the objects that have the id that I passed in the list of ids.
This is what I have tried so far, but it doesn't work.

```
    public UpdateResult deleteDispositivosByIds(String idCentro, List<String> ids) {
        // NOT WORKING--------
        
//      ObjectId objectId = new ObjectId(idCentro);
//      Query query = new Query();
//      query.addCriteria(Criteria.where("_id").is(objectId));
//      Update update = new Update();
//      BasicDBObject[] boArray = new BasicDBObject[ids.size()];
//      String[] idsArray = new String[ids.size()];
//      idsArray=ids.toArray(idsArray);
//      for (int i = 0; i < boArray.length; i++) {
//          boArray[i]=new BasicDBObject("uid",idsArray[i]);
//          System.out.println(idsArray[i]);
//        }
//      update.pullAll("dispositivos",boArray );            
//      mongoTemplate.updateFirst(query, update, "centros");
//      return null;
        
        // NOT WORKING--------
        
//      ObjectId objectId = new ObjectId(idCentro);
//      Query query = new Query();
//      query.addCriteria(Criteria.where("_id").is(objectId));
//      Update update = new Update();       
//      update.pullAll("dispositivos",ids.toArray() );          
//      mongoTemplate.updateFirst(query, update, "centros");
//      return null;
        
        // NOT WORKING--------
        
        ObjectId objectId = new ObjectId(idCentro);
        Query query = new Query();
        query.addCriteria(Criteria.where("_id").is(objectId));
        query.addCriteria(Criteria.where("dispositivos.uid").in(ids));
        Update update = new Update();       
        update.pull("dispositivos", query );            
        mongoTemplate.updateFirst(new Query(), update, "centros");
        return null;
    }
```

Comment: Here is an example SO post: [Not able to pull from nested array and query return sub-document using MongoTemplate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60510065/not-able-to-pull-from-nested-array-and-query-return-sub-document-using-mongotemp)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

that was my solution ( "centros" is the collection name):

```
    public UpdateResult deleteDispositivosByIds(String idCentro, List<String> ids) {

        
        ObjectId objectId = new ObjectId(idCentro);
        
        Query query = new Query();
        query.addCriteria(Criteria.where("_id").is(objectId));
        
        Update update = new Update();       
        update.pull("dispositivos", new Query(Criteria.where("uid").in(ids)) );
        
        return mongoTemplate.updateFirst(query, update, "centros");     
        
    }
```